# Who changed the job schedule on a SQL Server Agent Job (SQL 2000)

Tags: sql-server-2000

Someone (or some unknown process) changed the job schedule on 
a SQL Server Agent Job on a SQL 2000 database. The original 
start time was 6:00, but was changed to 4:45; that much I can determine.

Is there a way to find the history of changes 
involving what user may have altered the job time
and at what time they altered the schedule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without reading the transaction log and/or log backups (which may be impossible, if msdb is set to the default simple recovery), I can't think of any good way.

Going forward, if you want to log the changes, you could create some log tables, and add logging triggers to these tables in msdb.

```
sysjobs
sysjobsteps
sysjobschedules
```

I checked those names on 2008, but I seem to recall they have the same names on 2000 (though the structure may differ).